# How to compile a program with GEOS library

Tags: c, linker, geospatial, geos

I have written a small C program to access libgeos (https://github.com/libgeos/geos) functions.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include "geos_c.h"

int main()
{
    printf("Test");

    GEOSGeometry *inputGeom = GEOSGeomFromWKT("MULTIPOLYGON (((30 20, 45 40, 10 40, 30 20)), ((15 5, 40 10, 10 20, 5 10, 15 5)))");

    return 0;
}
```

But the compiler gives me an error when I try to compile this.

```
ab@abc-pc:~/learn-c$ gcc geos_test.c 
/tmp/ccugTUqF.o: In function `main':
geos_test.c:(.text+0x21): undefined reference to `GEOSGeomFromWKT'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

It seems that the linker is failing to link libgeos. I'd be really appreciated if someone can help me to resolve this since I'm a newbie to the C ecosystem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [github doco](https://github.com/libgeos/geos):

You need to link with the `libgeos_c.a` library, e.g.:

```
gcc -g -Wall geos_test.c -o geos_test -lgeos_c
```

(That is, the last item on the command line)

This produces an executable named `geos_test`, with debugging info included.